# Flutter: How to define model for firestore collections or datatype for firestore fields?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model defined in my project called `MyDeviceModel`. Each individual document from a particular collection on firestore fits into the `MyDeviceModel`.

```
  final CollectionReference myDevices =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("myDevices");

  Future<List<MyDeviceModel>> all() async {
        return myDevices.where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).get().then(
              (value) => value.docs
                  .map(
                    (e) => MyDeviceModel(
                      id: e.id,
                      name: e["name"],
                      uid: e["uid"],
                      deviceID: e["deviceID"],
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            );
      }
```

The code seems to work as expected. But the problem is with `package:lint`.
When enabled I get error highlight like `The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentReference<Object?>?'. dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`.

For some reason I need to make the code lint proof.

Here are some of the ways I have tried and why it didn't solve my issue.

1. Define a constructor `MyDeviceModel.fromFirestore()` that accepts `QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> data` as argument.
   It didn't work because `data["any_field"]` is again dynamic and cannot be assigned to the params of my model.
2. Define the argument `e` in the map function as `QueryDocumentSnapshot<MyDeviceModel?>`. It didn't work because because `The argument type 'MyDeviceModel Function(QueryDocumentSnapshot<MyDeviceModel?>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>)`.
3. Change `.map()` to `.map<MyDeviceModel>()`. It didn't do anything.

I could exclude these files from lint but I believe there exists a solution for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

**TL;DR:** I want to convince `package:lint` that `e["deviceID"]` is actually a `DocumentReference`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here.

Found the solution.
Added  `as DocumentReference` while assigning to a `DocumentReference`. Got rid of the error highlight.

```
  Future<List<MyDeviceModel>> all() async {
    return myDevices.where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).get().then(
          (value) => value.docs
              .map(
                (e) => MyDeviceModel(
                  id: e.id,
                  name: e["name"] as String,
                  uid: e["uid"] as String,
                  deviceID: e["deviceID"] as DocumentReference,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        );
  }
```

If anyone has a better answer I am more than willing to give the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement JSON encode and decode in your logic so you can work with models and not objects.

I'm your model you can implement fromJson and toJson methods.

I advice you to read this doc
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: I have used JSON encode/decode with flutter before but not sure how to implement in this scenario. Do you mind giving an example?